# How to pass array of of hashes from form to controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have services fields that can be duplicated multiple times(using JS), and they need to be saved in PostgreSQL database.

Database schema:

```rb
  create_table "working_acts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "services", array: true
  end
```

Controller:

```rb
def new; end

def create
  @working_act = WorkingAct.new(working_act_params)
  if @working_act.save
    render json: { data: 'Working act created!', status: 201 }
  else
    render json: { error: @working_act.errors.full_messages, status: 422 }
  end
end

def working_act_params
    params.require(:working_act).permit(services: [])
end
```

My spec factories which has the correct data for services:

```rb
services: [{title: 'Create design', describe: 'Create design for Article page'}, 
           {title: 'Update back-end', describe: 'Update back-end for Article page'}]
```

My form which can be duplicated several times using JavaScript:

```rb
.row id="01"
  .form-group
    = f.label :title, class: 'control-label'
    = f.input :title, class: 'form-control'
  .form-group
    = f.label :description, class: 'control-label'
    = f.input :description, class: 'form-control js-select-ua'
  .form-group
    = f.label :action, class: 'control-label'
  .form-group.form-actions
    = button_tag 'Add new', type: 'button', class: 'btn js-duplicate-act'
```

But I got an error `Unpermitted parameter: :services` and I cannot pass more than one set of parameters, saves only the last set of hashes.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: can u share the whole form?

Comment: Using array/json columns to store multiple values in a single column is an anti-pattern since it violates [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Using a separate table is almost always going to be a better solution. https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/03/database-modelization-anti-patterns/

Answer (score 1):

The name attribute of the inputs gets turned into the keys of the formdata pairs sent to your server.
To pass arrays use empty brackets:

```
irb(main):001:0> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3")
=> {"foo"=>["1", "2", "3"]}
```

Hashes are created by using brackets as well:

```
irb(main):002:0> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("foo[a]=1&foo[b]=2&foo[c]=3")
=> {"foo"=>{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3"}}
```

For an array of hashes combine the two:

```
irb(main):005:0> str = "services[][title]=foo&services[][description]=foo&services[
][title]=bar&services[][description]=bar"

irb(main):006:0> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(str)
=> {"services"=>[{"title"=>"foo", "description"=>"foo"}, {"title"=>"bar", "description"=>"bar"}]}
```

You don't really need to do this manually though. `fields_for` can be used to generate scoped inputs. But you really want to ditch the idea of using an array column and create an actual table and an association that you can iterate through:

```
class WorkingAct
  has_many :services
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services
end
```

```
class Service
  belongs_to :working_act
end
```

```
form_with(model: @working_act) do |form| 
  form.fields_for(:services) do |f|
    .row
      .form-group
        = f.label :title, class: 'control-label'
        = f.input :title, class: 'form-control'
      .form-group
        = f.label :description, class: 'control-label'
        = f.input :description, class: 'form-control js-select-ua'
      .form-group
        = f.label :action, class: 'control-label'
      .form-group.form-actions
        = button_tag 'Add new', type: 'button', class: 'btn js-duplicate-act'
```

```
def working_act_params
  params.require(:working_act)
        .permit(
          services_attributes: [:title, :description]
        )
end
```

See:

- https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for